# how to update a site on umbraco using an old database

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Hello Everyone please i have a small issue with my company's website
I recently migrated my website from 1and1 dedicated server to Godaddy shared server
I copied all the file including the media file located in the website folder from 1and1 to Godaddy
But i failed to copy the database but 1and1 has locked me out of their server
Although i still had the website database stored on a local server which i used for the website on Godaddy
Now i have issues updating the content on Umbraco, because most of the files are not found
There is a certain slider i want to delete but i cant because i cant find it on Umbraco
Please who can help?

Comment: Missing files can be retrieved by updating theme, plugins & WordPresss. However if you missed any media files and you don't have them on your local computer either. They probably will be lost.

Comment: File a support ticket with 1and1 to see if you can get access to the file system and database. It's important that your media folder and your database are up to date with each other, otherwise you'll have mismatches like what you're experiencing now.